# I have a wbpage where everytime based on start and end date the textboxes increase and decrease I am not getting proper row count and txtbox coun

Tags: python, selenium

This is the code  iam using to count number of rows, it is returning only 1:
tablen = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_tblForecast"]/tbody/tr')
tblength = len(tablen)
print(tblength)
Result : it is printing output as 1, but their are many rows

```html
<table id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_tblForecast">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class="separatorLabel" colspan="15">Quarter 4 2021</td>
                                    </tr><tr>
                                        <td align="right" style="width:180px;">2021 November</td><td class="nonrequiredblock"></td><td class="ctl" style="width:160px;"><span id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202111_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Silk" style="width:80px;"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202111" name="m$mc$s0$z0$C$ctl00$c202111" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="0.00" type="text"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202111_ClientState" name="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202111_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;minValue&quot;:0,&quot;maxValue&quot;:70368744177664,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;0.00&quot;}"></span></td><td align="right" style="width:180px;">2021 December</td><td class="nonrequiredblock"></td><td class="ctl" style="width:160px;"><span id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202112_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Silk" style="width:80px;"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202112" name="m$mc$s0$z0$C$ctl00$c202112" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="0.00" type="text"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202112_ClientState" name="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202112_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;minValue&quot;:0,&quot;maxValue&quot;:70368744177664,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;0.00&quot;}"></span></td>
                                    </tr><tr>
                                        <td class="separatorLabel" colspan="15">Quarter 1 2022</td>
                                    </tr><tr>
                                        <td align="right" style="width:180px;">2022 January</td><td class="nonrequiredblock"></td><td class="ctl" style="width:160px;"><span id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202201_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Silk" style="width:80px;"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202201" name="m$mc$s0$z0$C$ctl00$c202201" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="0.00" type="text"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202201_ClientState" name="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202201_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;minValue&quot;:0,&quot;maxValue&quot;:70368744177664,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;0.00&quot;}"></span></td><td align="right" style="width:180px;">2022 February</td><td class="nonrequiredblock"></td><td class="ctl" style="width:160px;"><span id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202202_wrapper" class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Silk" style="width:80px;"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202202" name="m$mc$s0$z0$C$ctl00$c202202" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="0.00" type="text"><input id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202202_ClientState" name="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_c202202_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;emptyMessage&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationText&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;valueAsString&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;minValue&quot;:0,&quot;maxValue&quot;:70368744177664,&quot;lastSetTextBoxValue&quot;:&quot;0.00&quot;}"></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the website link?

Comment: I am really sorry, I cannot moreover we need vpn for the site to open but any doubts i can clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing here in answer section as I have a snapshot to paste.
Is your locator correct? I built hmtl of your code and inspected DOM, and although your locator shows 4 element length, they doesn't seem to be the right ones.
See the snapshot here, [DOM snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4vEU.png) The locator highlights to a row with which you cannot do anything much useful. I have written some code block. Please check if this would be useful to you.

```
driver.get("url here")
time.sleep(3)
x = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_tblForecast']//tbody//tr")
print(f"Length of the element x is: {len(x)}")
date_txt = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='ctl']//../td[@align='right']")
print(f"lenght of date_txt is {len(date_txt)}")
ls=[i.text for i in date_txt]
print(ls)

ctl = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='ctl']//input[@type='text']")
print(f"length of ctl element is: {len(ctl)}")
for ele in ctl:
    ele.clear()
    ele.send_keys("1.00")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(ele.get_attribute('value'))
```

Output:

```
Length of the element x is: 4
lenght of date_txt is 4
['2021 November', '2021 December', '2022 January', '2022 February']
length of ctl element is: 4
1.00
1.00
1.00
1.00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you soo much your code is working, I had tried the same code earlier, it was not working mistake was that I had given the below Xpath :                                                                                                      
  //*[@id="m_mc_s0_z0_C_ctl00_tblForecast"]/tbody/tr where only single forward slash was their

Comment: Also please help me with anylink on how to create xpaths your code eased my work thanks

Comment: @SabaTaranum, you can check various sources of Google. Here is a quick link where you can learn how to make xpath [link](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html). Also, please not limit yourself to xpath, you may use Classname, CSS Selector, Name, Linktext, etc. Please explore.

Comment: Thanks  @Anand  sorry I am a beginner in python with self learning, your code is working perfect but the logic I understood a little is their a way to connect with you, to learn or ask upcoming doubts?